# How to open a particular android Activity with its layout from flutter

Tags: android, android-activity, dart, flutter

I want to launch a particular android `Activity` (having its layout) on the button pressed from flutter. I had used the platform-specific code but it open as a launcher activity always.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post the code you tried to open the `Activity`?

Comment: From your launcher activity, you should call startActivity with correct intent, if not it will stay always at launcher activity.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

```
  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
     super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
     new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
      (call, result) -> {
        // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
        // TODO
        // Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        // startActivity(intent);
      }
    );
```

}